# Trying to overwrite open file with move /y but "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file to compile Latex. I want to keep my pdf file open in Abobe Reader while I recompile so I wrote the following:

```
move /y build\output\rapport.pdf build
```

/y option to attempt to overwrite, but it gives me the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: The error message is quite clear. What don't you understand?

Comment: I want to force the script to overwrite. Is this possible?

Comment: Not while it is open by another program. Some programs don't hold files open like notepad (they open, read or save, then close). But most do.

Comment: Just insert a `taskkill /F /IM AdobeReader.exe` command before the `move...` **`:)`**